# Shortest MySQL string for date insertion (yyMMdd HH)

Tags: mysql, date, insert

(in this text I am using .NET notation for the dates)

The queries have to be sent to a distant server, so the shorter the insertion string the better. I also hope shorter strings lead to shorter insertion times but in no way I can be sure about that. But transport optimization is a priority.

Trying to optimize the date insertion. My date information contains: 'yyyy MM dd HH' (minutes and seconds are always set to zero).

What works : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

After some research I found that the shortest way to set 'yyyy-MM-dd' in MySQL : 'yyMMdd'. Note that this does not include the hour.

What is the shortest string that contains the information of 'yyyy MM dd HH' ?

Comment: This is the wrong problem. In the time it takes to get an acceptable answer, you could have moved onto something else.

Comment: With all the chatter that goes on over a database connection I seriously doubt you could measure the difference in performance between using what your using now and a format that's a couple of bytes shorter.

Comment: it is a bulk insert formatted as: `(<floatValue1>,<date1>),(<floatValue2>,<date2>), ... ,(<floatValue1000>,<date1000>)`. 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' => 19 chars. 'yyMMdd HH' => 9 chars. So maybe I am wrong but my guess is that a good optimization of the string could easily lead to 30% less data to be sent to the distant server.